# Interactive (non-daemon) applications that uses client credentials

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

In the "[Scenario: Daemon application that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview)" Microsoft says : "There's another common case where non-daemon applications use client credentials: even when they act on behalf of users, they need to access a web API or a resource under their own identity for technical reasons."

And that's exactly what I need. A web application with an authenticated to AAD user, but with an ability for application to make a calls to MS Graph with elevated permissions (more than user has).

There is an example under "[Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#code-samples-and-other-documentation)" called "[ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-daemon-webapp)"
which is very close, but it uses asp.net.

Does anybody have a **.net core** sample code of the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with [A .NET Core 2.2 simple daemon console application calling Microsoft Graph with its own identity](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph). It will show you how to create the MSAL confidential client, acquire a token and use it to call Graph.